# my bot not playing the music from URL (search)

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

This is my code for music bot and play url, I use YouTube-Search and youtube.dl

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, search):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    yt = YoutubeSearch(search, max_results=1).to_json()
    print('search a "{search}"')
    try:
        yt_id = str(json.loads(yt)['videos'][0]['id'])
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")

    [...]
    
    ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
    yt_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + yt_id
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(video_link, download=False)
      URL = info['formats'][0]['yt_url']
    voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

Comment: Please add the error traceback if you get one, or more details.

Comment: There is no print error in my terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```py
import asyncio

import discord
import youtube_dl

from discord.ext import commands

# Suppress noise about console usage from errors
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    "before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5",
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(description="joins a voice channel")
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None or ctx.author.voice.channel is None:
            return await ctx.send('You need to be in a voice channel to use this command!')

        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            vc = await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
            vc = ctx.voice_client

    @commands.command(description="streams music")
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.client.loop, stream=True)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Now playing", description=f"[{player.title}]({player.url}) [{ctx.author.mention}]")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @play.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
                raise commands.CommandError("Author not connected to a voice channel.")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
```